# How to make infinite-scroll plugin works in a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, infinite-loop

There is a fixed-height `div`, which has scrollbar. When its only-child element `ol` being scrolled to the bottom, the `ol` needs to load more new `li`.

I'm using jQuery [infinite-scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) plugin.

I can't get the plugin to work in the aforementioned situation on desktop browsers.

In iOS, it sorta works, and is buggy. When I scroll the `ol` to the bottom, it doesn't load. And then when I try to scroll the `ol` more (it actually can't be scrolled more), it successfully loads.

<del>Here is [a simple demonstration](http://goo.gl/yHvSP6) of my code.</del>

Here is [the demonstration code](http://goo.gl/I5LaOf).

Comment: Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showcasing your problem. Don't post source code files for download.

Comment: @Bogdan, the plugin uses Ajax to load additional html pages so jsFiddle can't do that.

Comment: Try [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) then, it allows you to create multiple files and load them via ajax.

Comment: @Bogdan, thanks, I didn't know that website before. My OP has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the `infinite-scroll` documentation:

> **To scroll inside an element having overflow, use the local behavior.**

So rather than having a `#container` element that has the overflow, just use the infinite scroll on the list:

```
$('#container').infinitescroll({
    behavior: 'local',
    binder: $('#container'),
    bufferPx: 0,
    navSelector  : '#nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '#nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : 'li'       // selector for all items you'll retrieve
});
```

Having the `ol` as the `#container`:

```
<ol id="container">
```

Here's a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hkSGoAgy7UhaVUVrLgQb?p=preview) and there's the [relevant documentation](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/#scrolling-inside-an-element).

### EDIT

It seems that to use the `local` behaviour, you need to override a method responsible for determining if the scroll is near the bottom (although this doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the documentation). There is a file in the repository  [`/behaviors/local.js`](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/behaviors/local.js) that would need to be included to make this work, but I tried it and is doesn't seem to work properly. So instead you can use this code to take care of the those computations:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.infinitescroll.prototype, {
   _nearbottom_local: function infscr_nearbottom_local()
   {
       var opts   = this.options;
       var binder = $(opts.binder);

       return (binder.scrollTop() + binder.innerHeight() >= binder[0].scrollHeight - opts.bufferPx);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to load before scrolling to the bottom.

Comment: Any solution for the loading occurs too early?

Comment: I've updated my answer and the [working example link](http://plnkr.co/edit/hkSGoAgy7UhaVUVrLgQb?p=preview) in the answer.